# One table with 500 Billion records, how can I do that?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I want your help in project. I want to design Multi-language flashcard database. Which serves a huge number of users; each user can has any numbers of cards (words). I must store all study history for each card (word), for statistical purposes.

Suppose, we have 500000 users, each user has 10000 cards (words); each word has about 100 records (ex. If the answer is true or false). A sample way to store this history is by using following table:

User_Id,Word_Id,Date,Answer_Type

But this table will by with a huge numbers of records, about 500 Billion records. 
Is there any an effective way to do that, and it's doesn’t affect the query time.

Comment: This is an “I want a pony” question and it’s too broad to give a specific technical answer, making it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to attempt to solve this problem and show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level as well as to demonstrate your commitment to solving this problem.

Comment: You don't have 500,000 users. You have zero. Engineer for realistic goals, not hypothetical situations. If you're going to expect ~1000 people at launch, work with that goal in mind.

Comment: First get 10,000 entries before worrying about 500,000,000,000..

Comment: I think you can split out the data horizontally.  You can partition the users so that, for instance, users with names that start with "A" are in one table/database/server, etc. Users with "B" in a different table/database/server. and so on down the alphabet (or some other hash)  Do the same with words and records.  You'll have a lot of databases instead of a single database.  In this way, a query for user "Adam" doesn't even touch the database that holds the data for user "Billy".

Comment: I disagree with those comments suggesting that you should first acquire a small amount of data. I do think that, while designing your system, you MUST consider future conditions. As per your question, let's begin with the key considerations: (1) What is the expected rate of INSERTS? (2) How often are you going to query your table compare to the rate of inserts? (3) Are you going to RETIRE old data? If yes, what will be the RETIREMENT conditions?

Comment: @user2023861, consider how would it look querying tens of tables for statistical purposes.

Comment: **tadman** 
in this case i don't need any code, i just need idea, something like @user2023861's idea, but i am looking for effective idea

Comment: @tadman and  Victor
you can thinking about cumulative entries for long time, maybe one, two, three, .... ect

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
we will use sql server.

Comment: @FDavidov 
Thank for your understanding
Expected rate of INSERTS It will be highly. Because any user must daily use this application, each day at least 40 minutes. And each word just need 1 minute (for review). 
We will store daily entries for 3 months; any old entries will be change from daily entries to monthly, ex. If in March we have 2000 entries, after 3 months will be change to be 1 entry only.

Comment: @user2023861
your Idea is good, but it will need a lot of tables.
I hope i can find other Idea

Comment: "Idea" type questions are off-topic here. What you should do is look outside the range of tools you've usually used for this to see what other platforms can offer. Consider MongoDB, Cassandra, and so on. Again you **do not** have 500 million records today, you have zero, so as you accumulate more you can evaluate your situation and pick your path accordingly.

Comment: You are welcome. Just one bit of advise, having very many tables (as suggested by @user2023861) would imply statistical queries involving all those tables... BAD IDEA!!!! You haven't addressed one of my questions: Rate of queries vs. rate of inserts.

Comment: @FDavidov, queries rate it will be same as insert rate. because, In each session we query any card one time only, user will study or review this card (may many times), after user finish this card, we will insert the result, that means: one query, one insert.

Comment: Well, if I understood you and made the calculations correctly, you are expecting an **AVERAGE** of 230 selects + 230 inserts / sec on an indexed table with 500M records... I don't see this will work with a single table, so the idea of splitting it into a **limited** number of tables (say no more than 8) does make sense after all.

Answer (score 0):

one in our team suggest:
(1) use XML and store it in database. As XML data type
(2) divide user's words to small groups (Titles) about 20 cards in one group. Card means: one word in front side, and it is meaning in the back side.
(3) use word’s attributes (XML attributes) to store all history entries.

Ex.:

```
<Group>
  GroupNo:01
  TotalCards=20
  ……
  <Card>
    CardNo=1;
    FrontWord=EnW98347;
    BackWord=CnW7536;
    History=20180301,1 + 20180315,0 + 20180330,1;
    ……;
    ……;
  </Card>
     ……;
  <Card>
    ……;
  </Card>
</Group>
```

Where: 20180301,1=Date, True or false.

But I think this process may need more time in query. Also we need more storage space. 
 Any advices or comments about this

Comment: If you're worried about database bloat, this is the polar opposite of a good solution. XML is not a very efficient method of storing data and it's not relational.

Comment: @tadman: for my case, may XML is not good solution. 
but for your information,  please visit :
[link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server)

Comment: The big question is if you can index it, which given the really peculiar formatting here, I'm going to guess no.

Comment: @alzeenahtrad, no SQL DBMS includes a **MAGICIAN** so, at the end of the day, the XML has to be fully loaded, parsed, and the found structured information stored for fast access. This whole process is not for free in terms of processing power consumption. As such, this is a **_BAD IDEA_** wherever and whenever you need to perform this process at high frequency.